# Passing 2-D arrays with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble understanding the relationship between array notation and pointer notation for the two-dimensional case.

For 1-D, the functions `oneDPrinterArr` takes in an array with [] notation, and prints the string in the array. Function `oneDPrinterPtr` takes in a pointer to an array, which does not have [] notation but has a * for pointer. Both of these functions work.

However, when I move on to the 2-D case, if I swap out a bracket for a star, as in the case going from twoDPrinterArr to twoDPrinterPtr, I get an error `expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[4]’`

Is it possible to use pointer notation to pass 2-D arrays?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// 1
void oneDPrinterArr(char oneDArr[]){
        printf("%s \n", oneDArr);
    
}

// 2
void oneDPrinterPtr(char* oneDArr){
        printf("%s \n", oneDArr);
    
}


// 3
void twoDPrinterArr(char (twoDArr[][4])){
    
    for(int i = 0; i <2; i++ ){
        printf("%s \n", twoDArr[i]);
    }
}


// 4
void twoDPrinterPtr(char (*twoDArr[4])){
    
    for(int i = 0; i <2; i++ ){
        printf("%s \n", twoDArr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char twoDArr[2][4];
    twoDArr[0][0] = 'T';
    twoDArr[0][1] = 'O';
    twoDArr[0][2] = 'M';
    twoDArr[0][3] = '\0';
    twoDArr[1][0] = 'C';
    twoDArr[1][1] = 'A';
    twoDArr[1][2] = 'T';
    twoDArr[1][3] = '\0';
    
    twoDPrinterPtr(twoDArr);
    oneDPrinterPtr(twoDArr[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Addition example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int M = 3;
 
 
void print(int (*arr)[M])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
}
 
int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    print(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you make an x by y array, it's a contiguous block of memory x by y, and not x pointers, each to blocks of y.  think about the difference between those a bit...

Comment: I have updated another example with source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/. the article uses what I believe the same notation as twoDPrinterPtr, with only difference being an int, instead of char. I thought about this a little more, and the only plausible explanation I can come up with is that the char* somehow is addressed by one pointer, whereas the int 2-D array contains three pointers? But I am not positive on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtle difference:

```
char (*twoDArr[4])

int  (*arr)   [M]
```

(The parentheses)

The first pair does nothing - `twoDArr` is an array of 4 pointers to char.

The second example makes `arr` first a pointer - one to an array of M ints.
Since `M` is a variable (even with `const`...), this is a *fixed-size* VLA.  This way it would make more sense:

```
void print(int M, int (*arr)[M])
```

Now it can handle different dimensions, if the caller gives that value.

**if I swap out a bracket for a star,**

The first, empty bracket can be replaced, but not the crucial other dimensions.

The other strategy is an *array of pointers*. I am not even sure if the terminolgy is 100% clear with "2D array". That is where you'd get a `char **` type; the first dim. moves by a pointer (to a row), not by a given number of elements directly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this subtle difference. I would not have figured it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use pointers for 2D arrays. `char **` doesn't represent a 2D array - it would be an array of pointers to pointers. This is how you would pass a 2D char array to a function `printarray`.

```
void printarray( char (*array)[50], int SIZE )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void twoDPrinterPtr(char arr[][4] ,int row ,int col)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("%c ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    char twoDArr[2][4] = {{'T' , 'O', 'M', 'C',} , {'A' ,'T' , 'P' ,'S'}};
    twoDPrinterPtr(twoDArr ,2 ,4);
    return 0;
}
```